# How to wire garage exhaust fan to humidity sensor/fan control and ventilation controller

Tags: exhaust-fan, humidity

I'm installing this [exhaust fan](https://www.industrialfansdirect.com/products/ff700) in my garage. I also want to install this garage [ventilation controller](https://www.aircycler.com/pages/garagevent), which is triggered when doors open and by temperature.

I also want to install a [humidistat/switch](https://www.leviton.com/en/products/iphs5-1lw) which is trigger automatically based on humidity and/or manual switch and Air Cycle mode which automatically turns ON the ventilation fan for a set period of time and repeats the cycle hourly.

I can bring power in to either the exhaust fan, humidity sensor/control or ventilation controller. How should I wire?

The way I understand it, they both are basically just single pole switches, so I should run them separately with power feeding each switch, leading to fan?

Comment: How do you want the control logic to work, and how are you planning to manually shut off the fan for servicing?

Comment: i didnt think of installing a switch to manully shut off for sericing, thats a good idea.  I already have a powered outlet in the ceiling, 2 ft away from the exhust fan, so it would be real easy for me to make that a double gang fixture in order to add a service, on/off switch for the fan.  So if I do that, power comes in at the exhust fan?

Comment: the garage vent controller is going to be located near the ceiling (best location for auto matic tempature sensing) and right above the corner of the garage door.  From the vent controller, two magnet door switches will be conected, one to the garage door and the other to the door leading into the house.  The garage vent controller works automaticlly, switch on the exhust fan when either of the doors are opened or when tempature rises to level set running for the desired minutes.

Comment: in addition to the garage vent controller, I wanted to install single pole humidty sensor and fan controller.  I would set in in the Air Cyle Mode, 10 min per hour. this switch would be installed in a three gang box besides a exterior door with two light switches.  There is power comming into this box as well.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the location of the garage vent controller is right beside a outlet that has power feeding into it.  I could change this outlet to a double gang box and install garage vent controller into the double gang box beside the outlet and I could feed power from here

Comment: lastly, in the process of drywalling garage, so everything is accessable right now, think new construction.  But this is dealing me from finishing the drywall, so I hope someone can help me ASAP.  thanks!

Comment: It's nice that we weren't a waste of your time, WaconiaLaker (a reference to several snarky comments you left), but you've wasted ours if you don't [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) and follow through with this question.

Answer (score 1):

### While it's OK to have switches in parallel...

While putting switching devices in parallel is not a *common* way of wiring a house, there is nothing in Code that forbids it, and it is done in other cases as well (such as multi-location occupancy sensor control).  However, such a configuration comes with caveats; most importantly, you'll need something to serve as a *disconnecting means* so that you can manually turn this fan off in case it needs servicing.  If you don't care about what else is on this circuit, then the circuit breaker will serve the purpose, though.

#### ... you need to be careful when you do so

Even with the issue of a disconnecting means addressed, you still need to be a bit careful with switches in parallel, to avoid inadvertently creating a looped or paralleled neutral situation, which can be read as violating NEC 300.3(B)/310.10(H).

### How to wire this

As a result, I would wire this by using a two-gang box at the power source location with the vent controller taking up one of the gangs, then running a new-style (neutral included) *switch loop* to where the humidity sensor goes and wiring that switch loop in parallel with the vent controller; this can easily be done by using black for always-hot, white for neutral, and red for switched-hot at each location, then connecting matching colors together.  You can then run switched-hot and neutral to the fan from whichever box is more convenient; just tape the switched-hot to the fan from black to red to make the colors match nicely.  This does rely on the breaker as the maintenance disconnect for the circuit, but provides neutral at both locations, as is required by the fan controller and humidity sensor you specified, and means that either device can command the fan on.

Comment: I was playing around with some things last night that seemed to work, before reading your post this morning, please tell me your opinion about what I did (seeing it's already done)before I switch everything to your current recomendation:

Comment: It makes sense to have a service switch nearby the exhaust fan, so ran power from the nearby outlet in the ceiling with 14-2 ground to a single pole switch in a new single gang box in the ceiling right beside the exhaust fan.  From there I ran 14-2 ground, whites connected, black switched to the exhaust fan location.

Comment: From there, I ran "two" 14-3 w ground wires, one leg going to a three gang box in which I placed the humidtystat/switch and the other leg into the double gang box above the garage door where the ventilation controller is located.

Comment: At the exhaust fan, I connected all the white together and grounds to a ground wire in exhaust fan.  I then connect the white wire from the 14-3 ground of each leg to their respective controller white terminal of each respective controller, black wire from the 14-3 ground of each leg to the black terminal of each controller and same with the red wire from the 14-3 ground to the red terminal of each controller.  I then connected both red wires from each of the 14-3 legs to the black wire in the exhaust fan.

Comment: I tested both controllers independently and together, along with the service discount, seems to be working fine. Your thoughts before I have to go back and change things?

Comment: I also realized the humiditystst switch automatically operates only in one of the three different modes and the manual switch only shuts it off (not what I'm looking for).  I currently have it running on air-cycler mode, 10 min on, 50 off.

Comment: I'm going to replace this switch with a 24 hour programmable timer with up to 50 set points and a switch which will allow me to manually turn the fan on/off https://www.leviton.com/en/products/vpt24-1pz.  I figure if I'm cycling air 5-7 min every hour, I really dont need to worry about having a automatic humidtystat.  On those few occasion where there is high humidity, I can manully switch the fan on for a longer period of time.

Comment: @WaconiaLaker -- the disconnect in the ceiling is slightly odd, but I can see the logic behind having it at the exhaust fan :) The double-spurred switching is fine, too, keeps things easy where it all comes together